# Not playing animation in Storyboard (using ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames)

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation

I can not play animation storyboard. Displayed only last picture animation.
What could be wrong?

My code create animation:

```
public static class AnimationHelper
    {
        private const string PathImageAnimation = "/LeSommet.ZooSnap.UI.WindowsPhone;component/Resources/Images/Animation/ButtonState{0}.png";

        public static void StartAnimation(UIElement target)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

            ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames objectAnimation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
            objectAnimation.AutoReverse = false;
            objectAnimation.SpeedRatio = 2;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(objectAnimation, new PropertyPath("Source"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(objectAnimation, target);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                DiscreteObjectKeyFrame discreteObject = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame()
                {
                    KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000),
                    Value = new BitmapImage(new Uri(string.Format(PathImageAnimation, i), UriKind.Relative))
                };
                objectAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(discreteObject);
            }
            storyboard.Children.Add(objectAnimation);


            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
```

My code Image xaml:

```
<Image Source="/LeSommet.ZooSnap.UI.WindowsPhone;component/Resources/Images/Animation/ButtonState5.png"                            
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Width="110" Height="110" Stretch="Fill"
                           x:Name="imageSquareAnimation">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are all of your keyframes at exactly the same time?

```
                KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000),
```

You could try:

```
                KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000 * i),
```

Try learning how to use Blend - it has an excellent editor to help you create animations.